# Subarrays allocation

Tags: arrays, algorithm, logic

I have an array, which is filled with numbers so that it contains empty and non-empty elements and in fact consists of several arrays. It may look like this:

0 **х х х 0 х х х** 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 **x х х х x х х** 0 0 **0 х х х** 
 0 **0 х х х х 0 х** 0 0 **0 х х х** 
 0 **х х 0 х х х х** 0 0 **х 0 х х** 
 0 **х х х 0 0 0 х** 0 0 **х х х 0** 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **0 х х х** 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **х х х х** 
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 **0 x x x x x** 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 **x x x x 0 x** 0 0 0

"0" means empty element
"x" means non-empty element

A man easily finds 3 subarrays here, but I wonder how to find them using a program. The difficulty is that the subarrays are not full, i.e. there are empty elements.
Is there an algorithm to cut the initial array into subarrays or maybe anyone can help me?
P.S. The subarrays' coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2): {2,1,8,5} {11,2,14,7} {6,9,11,10}. Also highlighted by bold

Comment: The man could have also formed more than 3 sub-arrays. I mean how are you dividing the array into sub-arrays? Is there some cost function associated on the number of sub-arrays and the number of empty elements?

Comment: There should be at least one empty row(column) between them. The amount of subarrays in undefined and should be calculated. The input is just an master-array m*n. It is possible to count empty and non-empty elements in the master-array. In other words, input is a huge array with a structure I've showed above and the output is an array(n,x1,x2,y1,y2), where n is index and x1,x2,y1,y2 are coordinates of a subarray.

Comment: Sorry, the output should be an Array(n,1 to 4), where n is index of a subarray and 1 to 4 are its coordinates x1,y1,x2,y2

Comment: The problem is still not clearly defined. What do you mean by "at least one empty row between them"? A complete, empty row or column? And also, why not just take the whole matrix? It also contains all non-zero elements. What's the optimization goal? Minimum area? Maximum number of rectangles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this problem in O(NM) time by using a union find data structure. Follow these steps:

`Step1`: Generate continuous horizontal lines in the matrix for adjacent filled elements. And label these lines with different numbers.

For this altered matrix

0 **х х х 0 х х х** 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 
0 **x х х х x х х** 0 0 **0 х х х** 
 
0 **0 х х х х 0 0** 0 0 **0 х х х** 
 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **х х х х** 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 
0 0 0 0 0 **0 x x x x x** 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 **x x x x 0 0** 0 0 0

The different lines of the matrix will become:

0 **1 1 1 0 2 2 2** 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 
0 **3 3 3 3 3 3 3** 0 0 **0 4 4 4** 
 
0 **0 5 5 5 5 0 0** 0 0 **0 6 6 6** 
 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 **7 7 7 7** 
 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 
0 0 0 0 0 **0 8 8 8 8 8** 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 **9 9 9 9 0 0** 0 0 0

`Step2`: Now initialize a Union Find data structure with all the different lines as separate clusters/sets in the data structure.

`Step3`: Start iterating over all the columns of the matrix. Whenever you encounter the beginning of a new line, check if there is some line exactly above or below that line. If there exists such a line above or below, then union the two sets that correspond to the adjacent lines in the data-structure.

`Step4`: Now that you have all the different clusters of lines at the end of the algorithm, you can easily calculate the boundaries of the clusters. And hence you have all the different sub arrays.

Running time: <strike>`O(NM)`</strike>   considering that we use a weighted quick union-find data structure with path compression providing O(α(n)) time (where α is the [inverse Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse)) for union operations. And since the inverse ackermann function grows very slowly, I am treating it as a constant.

**Edit:** The algorithm described will fail for this case (as told by user beaker in the comments)

1 1 1 1 1 
 
2 0 0 0 3 
 
0 0 4 0 0

To handle these types of cases, apart from the mentioned data structures, we will maintain an array that will contain the occupied rectangles of each row. So when we merge line 2 with line 1, the value for the 2nd row will become 0...4 indicating that there is a rectangle that covers indices 0 to 4 of the second row. Now when line 4 is considered in step 3 it will check if the points above or below are covered by some rectangle or not. And hence it will merge line 4's cluster with line 2's cluster.

The other parts of the algorithm will remain the same except that we now check if the adjacent points are covered by some rectangle or not.

The extra information that we are maintaing for all the rows will increase the running time. Whenever we consider the matrix column wise in Step3, we may have to do O(n) extra work. So the running time rises to `O(N^2 * M)`

Comment: This is basically the [Connected Component Labeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_labeling) algorithm, and will work fine as long as you can be sure that all of the non-zero elements are connected to the rest of their subarray. If not, you could miss rows/columns of the subarray.

Comment: I cant understand what you mean. I think it will work on all test cases. Do you have some test case on which the solution may fail?

Comment: Sure: row1 = `1 1 1 1 1`; row2 = `1 0 0 0 1`; row3 = `0 0 1 0 0`. It might be that row3 is trivially its own subarray, but if you duplicate the rows horizontally so that row3 is `0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...` it might be harder to dismiss.

Comment: A really good case. I will edit my answer to handle this case.

Comment: I was hoping you would have a brilliant idea :D The best I can come up with is once you have a bounding box, check each edge to see if there are non-zero elements in the next row/column within the proper range.

Comment: Invin, thank you a lot!!! I had a similar idea, but you significantly improved and perfectly formalized it.
Also great thank to beaker. I think that for my issue offered additional check is excessive though it is very usefull to know probable mistakes. Due to my small rating I can't vote for you, but I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: "amortized constant time for union operations." Actually it's O(α(n)) where α is the [inverse Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse).